# How do I create a cheap solar still?

Tags: water, water-management, solar-thermal, seawater

I am trying to create a cheap and easy way to distill water. I learned through some research and talking with people that making a solar still is the best way. I really would like a cheap solution to the water crisis around the world and I think this is the best way. I wanted to know is I make normal solar still paint it black and have a mirror or some other way to focus the suns rays into the water, would this be a good way to heat up the water. I also wanted to know if this has been done before, I have looked around and not seen anything like it. If this is not a good and efficient way to distill water then do you know what is?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Could you add your location to the question, or better yet the average day temperature?

Comment: BTW there's a related question [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5455/99)

Comment: @THelper I saw that I was just wondering about the mirror and fresnel lens. I also learned about Carbon paper and now I am thinking of a design. I still need help with the design if you want. Also, I am exploring lithium from seawater using desalination. Also, I live in Texas, but this is meant for people who need it, like people in India, Africa, and turkey. Also for fishermen or anybody on the coast.

Comment: You might get answers to this question on [GreatOutdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/).